# Italian DNS: How to avoid restarting firefox

Tags: firefox, dns

I'm using Firefox 3.5 on OSX.

When I try to go to a website that doesn't exist (because I forget to start my VPN), it brings me to the Virgilio search page.

```
http://auto.ricerca.alice.it/where.i.really.want.to.go.com
```

After that happens, I get to that page even once I start my VPN, unless I restart Firefox. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if that url is from your ISP trying to provide a fancy "domain not found" page to you, you should either disable that feature (I know at least it is possible with T-Online), or you should reduce the value of [Network.dnsCacheExpiration](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dnsCacheExpiration) on the `about:config` page.

Comment: Great. I will check if I can disable it, which would be on my router? Dealing with this ISP is best avoided :)

Comment: usually it is where you change your password or your billing address, or your bandwidth plan, i. e. on the website of your ISP.

Comment: OH god, you do not want to deal with the website of an italian ISP.

Comment: if you prefer, and the costs are not astonomically high (as it is with German ISPs) you can call its hotline instead ;)

Comment: good point, that would be free since they provide my phone. Except that I'd need to buy a physical phone :)

Answer (score 1):

Look in about:config for keyword.url. It should match that Italian website. Turn off keyword.enabled. Good luck!

Comment: Nope, that goes to google.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caching that site. Have you tried Ctrl-Shift-R to reload the page without the cache?

Comment: I'm not sure if that solves it. I'll report back after some testing. Thank you.

Comment: Nope that's not it, even persists if I try to start from the URL fresh. Thanks though.